# Android continuous acceleration processing in background

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I am developing an app that needs to process acceleration values continuously for some time (approx. an hour) - yes, I would really like to do it that way. The processing involves doing some calculations and updating the UI from time to time. The acceleration is collected inside a (foreground) service - collecting acceleration should happen if the user minimizes the app as well.

My question is: what would be the most appropriate pattern to implement this? I don't want the processing to make the app UI unresponsive.

Right now I'm collecting acceleration data in the UI thread (in the Service). The collected data is than passed to a class that does some calculations and based on them broadcasts an Intent, which is registered in the Main activity to update the UI.

Should I be collecting acceleration data in a worker thread in a service? (Is this even possible)?
Or should I do the processing in another thread? (How would be the best way to do this without starving either the UI/acceleration collection thread or the processing thread)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should be doing any non-trivial processing in a background thread. The easiest way sounds like it'd just be putting it into an `AsyncTask` called from your existing `Service`. You can move your processing to `doInBackground`. Another option would be to create a separate `IntentService` to handle your processing, but I think `AsyncTask` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

## Try an AsyncTask

```
public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      new PostTask().execute();
   }

   // The definition of our task class
   private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      displayProgressBar("Working...");
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         do_background_Stuff();

         // call this method whenever you want to run something in the UI thread and then get back to processing
         publishProgress(i);
      }
      return "All Done!";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      updateProgressBar(values[0]);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      dismissProgressBar();
   }
   }
}
```